# scrapy_selenium, how to pass driver to parse

Tags: selenium, parsing, scrapy, driver, scrapy-selenium

I'm running this code using scrapy_selenium but I'm not able to pass the driver to parse_page, can anyone identify what I'm doing wrong?

```py
class LSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield SeleniumRequest(
            url='https://www.url.com',
            wait_time=3,
            screenshot=True,
            callback=self.login
        )

    def login(self, response):
        driver = response.request.meta['driver']
        search_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input[@class='input__input'])[1]")
        search_input.send_keys("user")
        search_input_password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input[@class='input__input'])[2]")
        search_input_password.send_keys("password")
        search_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(3)

        yield SeleniumRequest(
            url='https:url.com/url',
            callback=self.parse_page,
            screenshot=True
        )

    def parse_page(self, response):
        driver = response.request.meta['driver']
        search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='search-box']")
```

Comment: What error do you get? Can you upload the output at this stage?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, just the empty output

Comment: Then maybe your xpath is wrong, what output do you expect?. In `parse_page` do you yield any items?

Comment: if i read that right, it looks like you are creating a new driver instance in the parse_page